# android MaterialBetterSpinner hint color doesn't change

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to change the color of material design better spinner, but nothing works,i tried to change it to color that defined in color or by define a style and use it in the theme:

```
android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
```

but nothing helped.

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
    android:id="@+id/some"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Range"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
    app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
app:met_textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
```

EDIT:
You can use any of these attribute as per your requirement:

```
  <attr name="met_baseColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_primaryColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabel">
        <enum name="none" value="0" />
        <enum name="normal" value="1" />
        <enum name="highlight" value="2" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="met_errorColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_minCharacters" format="integer" />
    <attr name="met_maxCharacters" format="integer" />
    <attr name="met_singleLineEllipsis" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_minBottomTextLines" format="integer" />
    <attr name="met_helperText" format="string" />
    <attr name="met_helperTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_accentTypeface" format="string" />
    <attr name="met_typeface" format="string" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabelText" format="string" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabelPadding" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="met_hideUnderline" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_underlineColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_autoValidate" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_iconLeft" format="reference" />
    <attr name="met_iconRight" format="reference" />
    <attr name="met_iconPadding" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="met_clearButton" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabelTextSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabelTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_bottomTextSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabelAlwaysShown" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_helperTextAlwaysShown" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_floatingLabelAnimating" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="met_textColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="met_textColorHint" format="color" />
```

what i used is:

```
   app:met_baseColor="@color/black"
   app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
   app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
   app:met_floatingLabelTextColor="@color/black"
   app:met_textColor="@color/black"
   app:met_textColorHint="@color/black"
   app:met_underlineColor="@color/black"
```

Comment: hi this helped me but still when it floating up it returns to the gray color, why??

Comment: Use  app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" for that.

Comment: yes , i founded it also, but i think this take the theme color, but anyway this is good for me too, better to have a way to change this also somehow, thx!!

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Comment: Thanks it helped me also, Can you tell what does the met_baseColor stands for? Rest I had understood, But met_baseColor I haven't got to understood, and where it is shown

Answer (score 0):

It work for me.

```
 <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.BetterSpinner
            android:id="@+id/classSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
            android:hint="Select Class"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" />
```

Comment: I use dependecies for it   compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }

Comment: i tried this now, this is not working by me :(    and also what about     floatingLabel= "highlight" how can i define it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this might be helpful for you

compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'

with

```
public class CustomMaterialSpinner extends MaterialBetterSpinner {

public CustomMaterialSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomMaterialSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}

public CustomMaterialSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (isEnabled())
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    else return false;
}

/*@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    this.selected = area[position];
}*/
```

}

Comment: i didn't understand how can it help me, can u explain?